# Ubuntu server remote access?

Tags: 12.10, server, samba, remote, ip-address

Hi i'm pretty new to the use of ubuntu server. i had a spare computer laying around and i figured i'd make it into a storage device.

I have been able to get the server to work on my home network but have had a lot of issues acessing it outside of it. all the forums i went on already talk about port forwarding and stuff and i've already done that. i'm using Samba as the FTP software and have no idea where to go from here. the static ip address that i assigned the server is 192.168.1.200 and its being forwarded for all ports 20-22 on the router side. any help would be greatly appreciated.

i"m not even sure how to find my external IP if thats a thing

Comment: http://www.whatismyip.com/

Comment: `curl -s http://myip.dnsomatic.com`. You can't actually find your own external IP from within your network. You have to ask someone that is outside it to check.

Answer (score 0):

Samba is not an FTP service, but a windows-based network filesystem.

You should install an FTP daemon, such as ftpd.

You can do this by:

```
sudo apt-get install ftpd
```

Or, you can look at the various related ftp daemons by using the command:

```
apt-cache search ftpd
```

And then install the one of your choosing.

[There is an official help page here, as well.](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/ftp-server.html)